System.XmlException: Illegal State: Current state END_ELEMENT is not among the statesCHARACTERS, COMMENT, CDATA, SPACEvalid for getText()
I have a button on a record page on click of which it calls an apex class with an integration logic to external system. But the process is failing with error midway:
EXCEPTION_THROWN [161]|System.XmlException: Illegal State: Current state END_ELEMENT is not among the statesCHARACTERS, COMMENT, CDATA, SPACE, ENTITY_REFERENCE, DTD valid for getText()
Below is my code:
XmlStreamReader reader = new XmlStreamReader(response.getBody());
boolean isSafeToGetNext = true;
while(isSafeToGetNext) {
if (reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT) {
                if ('xyz' == reader.getLocalName()) {
                    reader.next();  obj.Code__c = reader.getText();
                } else if ('pqr' == reader.getLocalName()) {
                    reader.next();  obj.pqr__c = Boolean.valueOf(reader.getText());
                } else if ('Name' == reader.getLocalName()) {
                    try{
                        reader.next();  
                        obj.Name__c = reader.getText();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex){
                        obj.Name__c = NULL;
                    }
                } else if ('County' == reader.getLocalName()) {
                    reader.next();  obj.County__c = reader.getText();
                } else if ('City' == reader.getLocalName()) {
                    reader.next();  obj.City__c = reader.getText(); //Getting error at this line
                } else if ('State' == reader.getLocalName()) {
                    reader.next();  obj.State__c = reader.getText();
                } else if ('Province' == reader.getLocalName()) {
                    reader.next();  obj.Province__c = reader.getText();
                } else if ('Census' == reader.getLocalName()) {
                    reader.next();  obj.Census__c = Integer.valueOf(reader.getText());
                } 
            }
            if (reader.hasNext()) {
                reader.next();
            } else {
                isSafeToGetNext = false;
                break;
            }
}

I checked logs and could see System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200] after which I'm getting this error. I tired adding try/catch to other fields but the error kept shifting to next field. I added null check on the reader.Next() but nothing seems to work. This is not happening for all records and few records are not throwing any error. I'm sure that this failing record might have some data missing from response but how to handle this instead of  throwing error on user UI.

Why are you hand-coding XML deserialization?

Why the error?
You get this error, because "City" seems to be an optional field. Assume you got
<City>Chișinău</City>
as a response body. The parser reads "City" as the start element, reader.next() moves the current element to "Chișinău" and "Chișinău" is read by reader.getText().
On the other hand, assume you got
<City></City>
as a response body. The parser reads "City" as the start element, reader.next() moves the current element to </City> and - ouch! - this element causes the "... Current state END_ELEMENT..." error, because reader.getText() fails.
A suggestion
That being said, there are simpler methods to parse flat XML like this. E.g. (assuming you have a root with some child nodes) you could first transform it to an Apex map:
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load(response.getBody());
Dom.XMLNode root = doc.getRootElement();
Map<String, Object> m = new Map<String, Object>();
for(Dom.XmlNode node : root.getChildElements()) {
    m.put(node.getName(), node.getText());
}

You could then work with this map, which is much simpler to handle. XmlStreamReader is generally more complicated to use and meant for large (I'd say several MB) inputs.
